# Limit Number of Cells with the Same Value in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm looking to limit the number of cells that can have the same value in a column.

More precisely, I'm keeping track of people signed up for meeting dates and once four other people are assigned that date, it not to be an option anymore or highlight the cell in red? Something to alert that the meeting is already full.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Comment: I removed the `google-apps-script` (GAS) tag you used because the answer to your question does not require something like this unless you explicitly want to use `GAS`.

Answer (score 1):

If highlighting the cell in red would be enough, then you can use this custom formula in your [Conditional Format Rules](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

**Apply to range** = `A1:A`

**Custom Formula:**

```
=countif(A:A,A1)>=4
```

**What it does?**

- Increment a counter if duplicates are found in the given range using [COUNTIF()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480)
- If the number of duplicates are >= 4 then set the background color of the cell to red

**Sample:**

[image]

---

**Another variation if you have a different list of available dates to highlight and a list of booked dates**

**Apply to range** = `A1:A`

**Conditional Formatting Custom Formula:**

```
=countif(C:C,A1)>=4
```

[image]

> Highlighting of cells will only be applicable in Column A. It will check how many duplicates data in Column A exist in Column C using [COUNTIF()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480)